# SHOW TABLES or INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: mysql

I need to get list of all tables on server in all databases.

I found out 2 ways for doing that.

1). Execute `SHOW FULL TABLES from <each database name> WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE';`

2). Execute `SELECT table_name, table_schema FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE = "BASE TABLE";`

Questions:

1). Is there any other method then mentioned above that can perform better?

2). Is there any performance difference in executing above two methods?

3). Which of the above two methods is better to execute?

Comment: Do keep in mind that the contents of information_schema depends on the access privileges of the connected user.

Comment: SHOW TABLES depends on privileges too.

Comment: I dont know the reason why, but when I tried, where Information schema seems to be taking around 30 seconds some times, work can be done in few milliseconds using SHOW TABLES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where possible, I would use `information_schema`. It is an [ANSI standard](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-information-schema.html), however, access to proprietary features of MySql may require use of the SHOW* functions on occasion.
So I guess it depends on your particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

Of course `information_schema`.`tables` is more preferable than SHOW TABLES statement (which was used in old MySQL versions < 5.0). It gives more useful information, it is standard system schema (you can find similar schema in other databases, e.g. SQL Server). You can use standard SELECT statement to retrieve information from this schema, I mean you can use WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY and other clauses and functions. But sometimes, on big databases, the performance of `information_schema` may be bad.

Have a look at the article about the `information_schema` performance: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema-optimization.html).

Comment: I only need table's name, nothing else. What do you suggest on that?

Comment: Then I do not see any differences. The performance should be equal/good in both cases. Just use one of them.